# ssh tunnel refusing connections to locally bound mysqld address

Tags: mysql, ssh, port-forwarding

I use port forwarding quite a bit to connect to remote databases with the following command:

```
ssh -L 3306:127.0.0.1:3306 -N foo@remote.ip
```

Where I believe the problem is on this particular server, the mysql daemon is bound to the private IP address (eg. `192.168.x.x`) rather than `localhost`.

This is the only thing I came up with from looking at the output when tunneling with `-v -v` options.

Example:

```
ssh -L 3306:127.0.0.1:3306 -N foo@remote.ip -v -v
```

And when I attempt to use the connection locally I get the following in the debug:

```
debug1: Connection to port 3306 forwarding to 127.0.0.1 port 3306 requested.
debug2: fd 7 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: fd 7 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 2: new [direct-tcpip]
channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
debug2: channel 2: zombie
debug2: channel 2: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 2: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 3306 for 127.0.0.1 port 3306, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 47520 to 127.0.0.1 port 3306, nchannels 3
```

I'm not new to using port forwarding and use it successfully in various other configurations, but this server in particular has me stumped.

Any help appreciated.

Edit:
<s>Worth noting the private IP address is assigned by a cloud provider and does not actually show up in `ifconfig/ip` output.</s> Yes it does, on eth0:1

Edit2: 
Mysql error output:

`200220 20:08:12 [Warning] IP address '192.168.x.x' could not be resolved: Name or service not known`

Edit3:

`ifconfig` output:

```
# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:XX  
          inet addr:xx.xx.xx.58  Bcast:xx.xx.xx.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: xxxx:xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8786400702 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8059726929 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1072200268259 (1.0 TB)  TX bytes:47891146981425 (47.8 TB)

eth0:1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  
          inet addr:192.168.xx.xx  Bcast:192.168.255.255  Mask:255.255.128.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:94 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:94 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:5360 (5.3 KB)  TX bytes:5360 (5.3 KB)
```

mysql.cnf output:

```
[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /var/tmpfs
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address        = 192.168.xx.xx
```

Comment: What do you get if you run `ssh -L 3306:192.168.x.x:3306 -N foo@remote.ip -v -v`?

Comment: @SmallClanger `debug1: channel 2: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 3306 for 192.168.x.x port 3306, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 47352 to 127.0.0.1 port 3306, nchannels 3`

Comment: That looks like a normal informational message about the connection attempt, rather than an error. Does the DB connection just time out or close/reject? Anything in the MySQL logs?

Comment: @SmallClanger MySQL error.log: `200220 20:08:12 [Warning] IP address '192.168.x.x' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
`  I wonder if this has to do with how the private IP is assigned. It is assigned by a cloud provider and doesn't actually show in any `ifconfig` output. I am curious if I played with my hosts file and added an alias for the private ip to localhost...

Comment: Can you add your `ifconfig` output to the question (and the relevant part of your `my.cnf`)? I don't think this is an ssh issue. Does the MySQL client connect from the local shell?

Comment: @SmallClanger  added additional info, also verified mysql users are able to connect via various hosts.

Comment: I have to ask at this point: What's the full private IP? (It's safe to share this as they're not routable from anywhere else). It struck me that `Name or service not known` is a name resolution error, which only occurs if the supplied address isn't a valid IP; the client will try to resolve it as a domain name.

Comment: Also, depending on your MySQL version, you might be able to specify multiple IPs in your config: `bind-address        = 192.168.xx.xx,127.0.0.1` to work around the problem. (https://mysqlserverteam.com/the-bind-address-option-now-supports-multiple-addresses/)

Comment: @SmallClanger I couldn't use that exact syntax (versioning) but did bind to 0.0.0.0 and that did the trick-- was able to connect as expected.  Thank you for your help, I'll select your answer if you add one.

Comment: Ok, but I'll add a large warning. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple workaround is to set (if you have the [correct version](https://mysqlserverteam.com/the-bind-address-option-now-supports-multiple-addresses/)), multiple `bind-address`es:

```
bind-address        = 192.168.x.x,127.0.0.1
```

If not, you can set

```
bind-address        = 0.0.0.0
```

**BUT** - The latter will also cause MySQL to listen on your public x.x.x.58 address, which is a significant security risk and not recommendated. If you must, you should take steps to ensure that connections to that port are blocked (iptables, ufw etc...) and test them from a remote location.